# How to get local JSON (fetch)?

Tags: reactjs

How to get local JSON (fetch)?

I do a service, then I call the class instance

This is not how it works:

Services.js

```
export default class ApiService {
    async GetPeople() {
        const request = await fetch('./data.json');
        if(!request.ok) {
            throw new Error('Что-то пошло не так', request.status)
        } else {
            return request.json()
        };
    };
};
```

Userslist.js

```
import Service from '../../../Services';

const UsersListContainer = () => {

    const api = new Service();

    useEffect(() => {
        api.GetPeople()
        .then(data => console.log(data))
    }, [api])

    return (
        <UsersListView />
    );
};

export default UsersListContainer;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to await the `.json()` the request before return:

```
export default class ApiService {
    async GetPeople() {
        const request = await fetch('./data.json');
        const json = await request.json(); // <--------------await the .json() here
        if(!request.ok) {
            throw new Error('Что-то пошло не так', request.status)
        } else {
            return json; // return it here
        };
    };
};
```

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: can you confirm that both files are in same directory?

Answer (score 0):

As Jai correctly said: You need to await the .json() method.
See: https://gist.github.com/msmfsd/fca50ab095b795eb39739e8c4357a808#gistcomment-2198304

Secondly I want to give you a recommendation:
export the ApiService as an singleton instance directly. Don't initialize the ApiService class inside your component and don't put the api as dependency in useEffect.

Reason: You ApiService class doesn't have any reason to create a instance anytime your UserListContainer gets mounted.